# Can't understand the question

Tags: sentence-meaning

> After identifying the term one might use to classify the expected lower rate of accidents in a country from the use of Autopilot and other self-driving vehicle software, discuss whether Tesla should wait until Autopilot is “10 times safer” than the average human driven vehicle before making it available to Tesla owners.

I am having hard time how to answer this question. Is the problem asking how to identify lower rate of accident? And discuss tesla should wait or not? Can anyone rephrase this question?

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: I think there must be an table of data associated with this question. Could you please tell us if that is the case, and perhaps include it, or describe it? This is to help me understand the "identifying the term" portion of the question.

Comment: No, this question was on one of my take home quiz..

Comment: There were no data or table. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading that question, without any further information available, I'd rephrase it as follows:

> Identify which term one would use to "classify the expected lower rate of accidents in a country from the use of Autopilot and other self-driving vehicle software". Next discuss if Tesla should make Autopilot available immediately, or wait until Autopilot is “10 times safer” (than the average human driven vehicle).